# Seaborn y labels are overlapping

Tags: data-visualization, data-science

So I tried to make a categorical plot of my data and this is what my code and the graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.set_style("ticks")
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1, rc={"lines.linewidth": 6})
sns.catplot(y = "Region",x = "Interest by subregion",data = sample)
```

Image:

[image]

How can I make the y-labels more spread out and have a bigger font?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sns.figure(figsize(x,y))` and `sns.set_context(context=None,font_scale=1)`.
Try different values for these parameters to get the best results.